Issue with flowbite-svelte
I'm relatively new to using flowbite and i just started using flowbite-svelte but for some reason the template isn't working, the hamburger menu works fine but the design isnt reflecting, any ways to fix this?
I deleted everything reinstalled the libary but no changes.




paste the code itself, not the screenshot of it

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/sveltekit
Import the CSS file
Create a ./src/routes/+layout.svelte file and import the newly-created app.css file.
 <script>
  import "../app.css";
 </script>

 <slot />

